# How is the PKCS#1 PSS different than the classical RSA Encryption method

Tags: python, rsa, digital-signature, pkcs#1

I want to perform a sha256withRSA signature of an hexadecimal string (0xDEADBEEF in this example) using the PKCS1_PSS module in Python:

```
import Crypto
from Crypto.Signature import PKCS1_PSS
from Crypto.Hash import SHA256
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto import Random
import binascii


message = 'DEADBEEF'
message = binascii.unhexlify(message) 


h = SHA256.new(message) # sha256 hashing the message
my_hash = binascii.hexlify(h.digest())
```

I get the following hash :

```
b'5f78c33274e43fa9de5659265c1d917e25c03722dcb0b8d27db8d5feaa813953'
```

Then I sign it using the following Private Key :

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Signing command :

```
key = RSA.import_key(open('private_key.pem').read())
signature = PKCS1_PSS.new(key).sign(h)
print(binascii.hexlify(signature))
```

The result :

```
b'67bcc8c0cd625a58272dc8808602beb630c0dc47622da153c6b3f7fcfdddd5e082beb9e73ed0e66f9751e68106b42ff71f8d291045ca7e9a5a265e885e19c016b6095e5f895801d3f735393e8cd3e4a18382a914487b46cf6c3ca3346c0b6f4bac923e491ca9933e12f826914b90955ce24d0203824dbb2c9cb7cb617af7cdef'
```

When I try to calculate the signature myself using the RSA encryption method (x = (m^d)%n ), I get a different value :

```
n = key.n
d = key.d
x = 0x5f78c33274e43fa9de5659265c1d917e25c03722dcb0b8d27db8d5feaa813953 # hash 
calculated_signature = pow(x,d,n)
print (hex(calculated_signature))
```

I get this :

```
'0x4e3484dde9ca8987b77a52c696b6848e5980c858f635a62e10fe24d45bea52bac4873378b9612f47398cb73102243b73cfa2da87b487ec0d26f949e09e4edb299bd4acc4aa0eb43afa47b814b3430ff9b01b8e41bcf53ba310ae26c191cb516c07f3ebe272bcbb95acb9e7bbdc22f0c17997ba6c1884c177ba41d4e384184275'
```

I'm wondering why I get this difference? My understanding of the `sign` method previously used is that it encrypts the input (the hash) using the operation (x^d)%n.

Am I missing something ? Can anyone suggest me the reason of the difference ? Is it due to some bad manipulation/understanding from my side ?

Comment: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8017 really has all the details.

Comment: Thanks @PresidentJamesK.Polk for sharing, but I couldn't find an answer as in Section 5.2.1 it explains the signature method by calculating m^d mod n which is the method I use myself

Comment: That's some very selective reading that you are doing, try [8.1.1](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8017#section-8.1.1). Note that PSS is randomized, so you'd get different values even if you implemented PSS yourself.